# Pass the name of a property in Twig?

Tags: twig

In PHP I can designate which element / property to use simply by passing a variable with the name of it, such as:

```
$array[$name]
$object -> $name
```

How to do this with Twig?

For instance, with an array row read from MySQL database whose primary key field can be id, ItemId, Serial, number, or anything, how can I pass in the column name of the primary key so Twig correctly displays the primary key of the row?

```
{{ row.id }}
{{ row.ItemId }}
{{ row.Serial }}
{{ row.number }}
```

But just something like:

```
{{ row.primary }}
```

Wherein primary is the name of the actual column name of the primary key, be it id, ItemId, or whatever.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems rather simple, just use [attribute()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html).

Pass:

```
array(
  'primaryKey' => 'id'
  'row' => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'some title'
  )
)
```

In twig template:

```
{{ attribute(row, primaryKey) }}
```

Which would have the same effect as:

```
{{ row.id }}
```